# twilio conversation tracking id

Tags: twilio

I am creating a chat application with twilio but having an issue tracking conversations among multiple users and multiple conversations.

Example:

conversation -> userA & userB

conversation2 -> userA & userB

When userA sends a message to userB in conversation2 when I receive a SMS message from userA how do I map it to conversation2?

What I am expecting:

What I am looking for is an ID that is either provided by me or generated by twilio and given to me when I send the SMS.  Then when I receive a SMS from twilio I can match it to a conversation by looking at the ID stored when the SMS was sent.

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

SMS does not have threading baked in, so this is not possible with just one phone number. You can prove this to yourself by opening the SMS app on your phone and trying to respond to the second to last message you received from someone.

You have two options:

1. You insist that your users include a specific ID within messages in a thread so that you can parse the message and extract the ID to tie the threads together.
2. You conduct separate conversations between the same users using different Twilio numbers. This way you can tie the thread together using the number that was used.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: thank you for the two options. Neither of these are ideal... i am very surprised twilio does not have a better solution to what I would think is a common issue.  Options 2 does not scale well when your app dynamically creates conversations.  Looks like I need to research alternate vendors.

Comment: You missed the point of my comment. You cannot reply to a specific message in SMS, only add messages to the thread. As far as I know, no one can accomplish this without the workarounds described.

Comment: @philnash option 1 is a bit tough, for the reason that you will be relying on the end user, which can open Pandora's door to all types of anomalies.  I can see number 2 working for a short/mid term solution because you will eventually run out of numbers.  I see this thread is a bit dated,  is there another work around that has come up.

Comment: I'm afraid the nature of SMS has not changed since 2017. I agree that option 1 is not the best. For option 2 you only need as many numbers as the maximum number of concurrent conversations with one user. Once a conversation is over you can reuse that number with them for a new conversation. The other alternative is just to ensure in your system that you only have one (or as many numbers as you're willing to use) active conversation(s) with your user.

Answer (score 0):

I know this response may be too late, but here goes anyway...

Conceivably, if Conversation 1 and Conversation 2 both are between different parties. You could create a mapping table of the endpoint phone numbers and just map the messages to the corresponding phone number.

Example:

```
Conversation 1 = UserA(1-234-567-8910) => UserA(1-234-567-8911)
Conversation 2 = UserC(1-234-567-8912) => UserD(1-234-567-8913)
```

If UserA sends a message, it will be forwarded to UserB, and vice-versa. Same goes for Conversation 2.

On the server side:

Upon the initial connection, the server would map that UserA wants to talk to UserB. This would remain in the lookup table until UserA stops wanting to communicate with UserB.

This would require that each user could only have one conversation going at a time, which may not fit for the purposes of the initial poster, but I hope that it will help someone.