# Twilio Can we add IDs to distinguish messages from the same number?

Tags: sms, twilio, message

We're building a live chat-like software and we're trying to connect it through Twilio to send SMS messages to our clients' staff members. We've built a backend base in our control panel that would allow staff members to reply to the users through our system (it would send them an SMS back through Twilio).

Our system is built so that a user can send text messages based on a specific interest, which would create a new lead (for that interest type) entry in our system (as well as notify the staff with SMS). We'd like to be able to show a threaded SMS conversation back and forth between the users and the staff members for each of those separate leads/threads.

It's not a simple one-to-one conversation between the user and a staff member because the same user phone number can have multiple threads for each lead type. Is there a way to somehow tag messages so we can detect which thread they belong to?

Comment: Try with including hashtags from users, 1st sms should start with a hashtag, the next messages will continue that conversation until the hashtag is changed. eg. if you have department like sales, service you can create hashtag for those department which help to route the message to particular agent at the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The limitation here is the SMS platform. You can see, if you open up your own phone's SMS application, that SMS messages are delivered in chronological order only. You can only reply to the last message sent, not a different message in the history. There is no message threading in SMS.

You have two options:

1. You insist that your users include a specific ID within messages in a thread so that you can parse the message and extract the ID to tie the threads together. Or, as Digant Shah suggested, use an ID and then assume every message is for that ID until a new ID is used.
2. You conduct separate conversations between the same users using different Twilio numbers. This way you can tie the thread together using the number that was used.

I've had this conversation in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763080/twilio-conversation-tracking-id) before, and the follow up might help too.

Let me know if that helps at all.